# How to declare a public static pointer in rust?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I just wanted to declare a pointer to a struct in a crate shared by several components of my project but using the same process. I mean the aim is to get it initialized only once.

```
type Box = [u64; 64];
pub static mut mmaped: &mut Box;
```

which at compile time [generated this error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb9a09e43bf6495eb950fcea1a967ae6).

```
free static item without body
```

Where `mmaped` is later assigned a value in the following way only one time from the top crate and it s value used from the multiple crates it depends on.

```
mmaped = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(addr) };
```

So how do I provide a definition of `mmaped` without having to `mmap` it more than one time?

This question isn't a duplicate of [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532), as it doesn't talk about exporting the singleton outside the crate and I'm getting a compiler error specifically for doing it.

Comment: @pretzelhammer I edited my question, but this doesn t appears to apply exactly to my specific case as it doesn t explain how to get it exported outside the crate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre] that either (1) demonstrates the error you're currently getting or (2) compiles but does not have the desired behavior (and explain what the desired behavior is). In particular, it's not clear what you mean by "without having to mmap it more than one time". `mmap` is a [specific thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap); if you're not referring to that you should probably try to find different words to describe the behavior you want.

Comment: @trentcl `type Box = [u64; 64]; pub static mut mmaped: &mut Box;` is the minimal example trigerring the error.

Comment: @trentcl https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb9a09e43bf6495eb950fcea1a967ae6

Comment: Um... ok... I must be missing something. You can't declare an uninitialized `static`, that's what the error is telling you. It's not valid code because it doesn't *mean* anything. So... what do you want it to mean? Maybe you want to create a static `Option`? (``pub static mut MMAPPED: Option<&mut [u64; 64]> = None;``)

Comment: @trentcl but then, it s value will be reinitilized to `None` each time my crate is loaded by a new thread?

Comment: No, spawning a new thread does not re-initialize static variables, which are shared between threads. If you wanted that behavior you would need to use `thread_local`. (But realistically you probably want to use `lazy_static` instead of `static mut`, which is prone to UB if you are not extremely careful)

Comment: @trentcl this doesn t seems to be the case as show by this playground https://stackoverflow.com/a/65270812/2284570.

Comment: There's no `static` in that example, just two local variables initialized separately.

Comment: @trentcl I m meaning this since the thread will load the crate one more time.

Comment: @user2284570 I realized that [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270748/when-implementing-the-default-trait-for-a-struct-and-intializing-its-members-us/65294420#65294420) was misunderstood, so I added an answer.

Comment: _"it doesn't talk about exporting the singleton outside the crate"_ It is unclear what stopped you from making the singleton public (`pub`) for other crates to access. Should that be clarified, it would eventually stop being a duplicate then.

Answer (score -1):

The Rust compiler (2018) is not able to generate a valid static item from your code because it lacks a body. You are attempting to declare a static variable `mmaped` but not actually initializing it with any value. All static variables must be initialized with a value at compile time.

`std::mem::MaybeUninit` seems to be a perfect solution for this use-case. Initialize it with an 'uninitialized' value. Later update it with your actual value. Since, it is static, it won't allow further initialization.

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
type Box = [u64; 64];
pub static mut mmaped: MaybeUninit<Box> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

// later
unsafe {
    mmaped = MaybeUninit::new([0; 64]);
}
```

Just make sure you don't access the `mmaped` before your actual initialization.

Comment: This seems much too risky and with little benefit over just exposing an `Option<_>` with synchronization mechanisms.