# Problems Translating C++ 'extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)' struct to Rust

Tags: c++, struct, rust, dllexport

I am currently attempting to rebuild and update a Project written in Rust (more specifically it's an SKSE64 plugin for Skyrim: https://github.com/lukasaldersley/sse-mod-skyrim-search-se forked from qbx2)
The last problem I'm facing is the library now requires a struct to be exported from our library for version checking.

I have attempted many probably stupid ways to implement this, but I can't get it to work.

The c++ code is as follows:

```
struct SKSEPluginVersionData
{
    enum
    {
        kVersion = 1,
    };

    enum
    {
        // set this if you are using a (potential at this time of writing) post-AE version of the Address Library
        kVersionIndependent_AddressLibraryPostAE = 1 << 0,
        // set this if you exclusively use signature matching to find your addresses and have NO HARDCODED ADDRESSES
        kVersionIndependent_Signatures = 1 << 1,
    };

    UInt32  dataVersion;            // set to kVersion

    UInt32  pluginVersion;          // version number of your plugin
    char    name[256];              // null-terminated ASCII plugin name

    char    author[256];            // null-terminated ASCII plugin author name (can be empty)
    char    supportEmail[256];      // null-terminated ASCII support email address (can be empty)

    // version compatibility
    UInt32  versionIndependence;    // set to one of the kVersionIndependent_ enums or zero
    UInt32  compatibleVersions[16]; // zero-terminated list of RUNTIME_VERSION_ defines your plugin is compatible with

    UInt32  seVersionRequired;      // minimum version of the script extender required, compared against PACKED_SKSE_VERSION
                                    // you probably should just set this to 0 unless you know what you are doing
};

#define RUNTIME_VERSION_1_6_318 0x010613E0

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) SKSEPluginVersionData SKSEPlugin_Version =
    {
        SKSEPluginVersionData::kVersion,

        1,
        "Skyrim Search",

        "qbx2",
        "",

        0,  // not version independent
        { RUNTIME_VERSION_1_6_318, 0 }, // RUNTIME_VERSION_1_6_318 is 

        0,  // works with any version of the script extender. you probably do not need to put anything here
    };
};
```

What I've come up with so far in Rust is:

```
enum KVersionenum {
    KVersion=1,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct SKSEPluginVersionData {
    dataVersion: u32,

    pluginVersion: u32,
    name: [char;256],

    author: [char;256],
    supportEmail: [char;256],

    versionIndependence: u32,
    compatibleVersions: [u32;16],

    seVersionRequired: u32,
}

//0x010613E0 is RUNTIME_VERSION_1_6_318

//how can I do this OUTSIDE of a method and how can I make it public to the dll? is that even possible?
let SKSEPlugin_Version = SKSEPluginVersionData {
    dataVersion: KVersionenum::KVersion as u32,
    pluginVersion: 1,
    name: "Skyrim Search\0", //this doesn't work, how can I fill this char array?
    author: "qbx2 / lukasaldersley\0", //same here
    supportEmail: "something@something.something\0", //and here
    versionIndependence: 0,
    compatibleVersions: [0x010613E0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], //I'm sure this is a horrible way of doing this
    seVersionRequired: 0,
};
```

When I tried to use the let thingy outside of a function the compiler complained about expecting 'item' but my google-fu isn't good enough to find any useful information there because I just kept finding information about items in the videogame Rust.

For the car array/string problem I have come across that std:ffi stuff and am completely lost in it's documentation but as far as I can tell it will only ever deal with pointers, which is not what I need.

The two questions now are how to I fill these char arrays (I cannot just pass a pointer) and how do I create an instance of this struct as a global variable (or however Rust calls it) that I can export since the let name = something {...} doesn't work.

As far as I can tell exporting to the dll for a function would look like this, but I assume it wouldn't work the same way for that struct.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn SKSEPlugin_Query(skse: *const SKSEInterface, info: *mut PluginInfo) -> bool {...}
```

Is it even possible to do this?

Could someone help me here or at least point me in the right direction?
Please note I am an absolute beginner to Rust and apparently falsely assumed just adding a struct wouldn't be so complicated.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no syntax in Rust to export a global variable. Probably your best bet is to write that variable in C, compile that into an object file and link it into the rest of your Rust DLL.

Comment: @rodrigo does this not work: [Can a Rust constant/static be exposed to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701655/can-a-rust-constant-static-be-exposed-to-c)

Comment: @kmdreko: Hmm, tricky... that declares a global variable but does not dll-export it. In Windows you need to `__declspec(export)` the symbol. I seem to recall that you can also do that in a DEF file, used as input to the linker, or even as a [direct argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=msvc-170) to the linker, but it's been a while since I hacked on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a `char` in Rust is a 32-bit value while its 8-bit in `C++` (that's not [strictly true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727465/will-a-char-always-always-always-have-8-bits) but Rust doesn't support architectures where it isn't). So the
`name`, `author`, and `supportEmail` fields should be `u8` arrays.

---

You can export a global value by using `#[no_mangle]` on a public `static` variable:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub static SKSEPlugin_Version: SKSEPluginVersionData = SKSEPluginVersionData {
    ...
};
```

See: [Can a Rust constant/static be exposed to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701655/can-a-rust-constant-static-be-exposed-to-c)

---

You can initialize a `u8` array from a literal using a [byte string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-string-literals) and dereferencing it: `*b"..."`. Unfortunately, there's no shorthand like in C++ for zero-padding the undetermined part of the array, so you'd be left with:

```rust
    name: *b"Skyrim Search\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    author: *b"qbx2 / lukasaldersley\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    supportEmail: *b"something@something.something\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    compatibleVersions: [0x010613E0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
```

Which honestly, is not nice at all. You can clean this up with some functions that pad the array for you, however, initializing `static` variables requires `const` functions, which are still relatively immature in Rust so we can't use things like [`for` loops or traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792) to help us out:

```rust
const fn zero_pad_u8<const N: usize, const M: usize>(arr: &[u8; N]) -> [u8; M] {
    let mut m = [0; M];
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < N {
        m[i] = arr[i];
        i += 1;
    }
    m
}

const fn zero_pad_u32<const N: usize, const M: usize>(arr: &[u32; N]) -> [u32; M] {
    let mut m = [0; M];
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < N {
        m[i] = arr[i];
        i += 1;
    }
    m
}

...

    name: zero_pad_u8(b"Skyrim Search"),
    author: zero_pad_u8(b"qbx2 / lukasaldersley"),
    supportEmail: zero_pad_u8(b"something@something.something"),
    compatibleVersions: zero_pad_u32(&[0x010613E0]),
```

Still not that nice, but at least its manageable. There may be a crate available that can do this for you.

---

Lastly, you don't have to use the same field naming convention as used in C++ since its just the order and type that matters, so I'd recommend using `snake_case`, but if you do want to keep the same names for consistency, you can put the `#[allow(non_snake_case)]` attribute on `SKSEPluginVersionData` to suppress the compiler warnings.

I would also recommend making a constant for that magic value instead of just a comment:

```rust
const RUNTIME_VERSION_1_6_318: u32 = 0x010613E0;
```

See the full thing on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f91a0d95b55fa03665f3b1d83c52dfe2).

Comment: Thank you very much.
I implemented your suggestions and it does work.
I think you could remove the "this is all untested" note since I tested all of your code now.

Comment: @lukasaldersley nice! Will do. Glad it all worked out :)